# Need Help: Account Name on Contact Phone Call

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am new to CRM and have been able to figure out everything up to now. I have read so many post and internet post and tried them. I have watched some many videos. It seems it should be easy. The contact record has the ParentCustomerID, and ParentCustomerName that holds the account if there is one associated. Now I am just totally confused on the required steps.

Requirement: - I need Account Name to be displayed on the contact level phone call form and saved in phone call table so that it can be visible in the phone call view.

I have in Phone Call N:1 Relationship field str_companyid (lookup) primary Entity is Account with Referential behavior.

I tried a Phone Call N:1 Relationship field new_companystring (lookup) primary Entity is Contact with Referential behavior. I came to the conclusion that this is not a valid approach. Let me know if incorrect.

Do I need a N:N instead?

I have added the str_companyid field to the form. I went to the "Create a phone call for a contact" workflow process. On the "Create PhoneCall" step I have added the dynamic field {Company(Contact)}. After save and publishes; I created a phone call and it isn't populated.

I have tried different Web Resource JS. I have added the JS in the onload of the form properties.

Why doesn't something as easy as this work? I can't seem to get the retrieveRecord to work. I  have also tried the xmlHttpObject object but it returns 0.

Can someone help assist me on what I am missing? What are the complete steps to accomplish this?
![I have screenshots below and the code I was running][1]

```
function PopulateCompanyName() 
{

    //get group GUID
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue()[0].id != null) {

        var lookup = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue();

        alert(lookup[0].id);
        alert(lookup[0].typename);
        alert(lookup[0].name);

        alert(lookup);

        SDK.JQuery.retrieveRecord(lookup[0].id,
            lookup[0].typename,
            "ParentCustomerID",
            null, 
            function (lookup) {
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("Company").setValue(lookup[0].str_companyid);
         });
    }

    else {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("str_companyid").setValue(null);
    }
}
```

---

```
function GetCompany()

///Get lookup ID

{
alert("I am Here");
 var lookupfield = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue();
 if (lookupfield != null && lookupfield [0] != null)
 {
 var householdlookupvalue = lookupfield [0].id;
 }
 else
 {
 var householdlookupvalue = " ";
 }
alert("I am here2");
alert(householdlookupvalue);
}

// Prepare variables for a contact to retrieve.
 var authenticationHeader = Xrm.Page.context.getAuthenticationHeader();

// Prepare the SOAP message.
 var xml = ""+
 ""+
 authenticationHeader+
 ""+
 ""+
 "contact"+
 ""+lookupfield [0].id+""+
 ""+
 ""+
 "parentcustomerid"+
 ""+
 ""+
 ""+
 ""+
 "";
alert(xml );
// Prepare the xmlHttpObject and send the request.
 var xHReq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
 xHReq.Open("POST", "/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx", false);
 xHReq.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction","http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices/Retrieve");
 xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
 xHReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", xml.length);
 xHReq.send(xml);

// Capture the result.
 var resultXml = xHReq.responseXML;
alert("at results");
var errorCount = resultXml.selectNodes('//error').length;
alert("errorCount " + errorCount); ////////////////////////////////////returns 0; it shouldn't
alert("After the result XML "+resultXml .toString() + " ::::");

// Check for errors.
 var errorCount = resultXml.selectNodes('//error').length;
 if (errorCount != 0)
 {

}
 // Display the retrieved value.
 else
 {

//Create an array to set as the DataValue for the lookup control.
 var lookupData = new Array();

//Create an Object add to the array.
 var lookupItem= new Object();

//Set the id, typename, and name properties to the object.
 lookupItem.id = resultXml.selectSingleNode("//q1:parentcustomerid").nodeTypedValue;
 lookupItem.entityType = 'account';
 lookupItem.name = resultXml.selectSingleNode("//q1:parentcustomerid").getAttribute("name");
 // Add the object to the array.
 lookupData[0] = lookupItem;
alert(lookupitem.name)
// Set the value of the lookup field to the value of the array.
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("str_companyid").setValue(lookupData);
 }


    var contact = new Array();
    contact = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue();
alert("I am here");
alert(contact);
    if (contact == null || contact[0].entityType != "contact" || contact.length > 1) {
        return;
    }
alert("inside if")
    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    var oDataSelect = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ContactSet?$select=ParentCustomerId&$filter=ContactId eq guid'" + contact[0].id + "'";

    var retrieveReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    retrieveReq.open("GET", oDataSelect, false);
    retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    retrieveReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
    retrieveReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
        GetContactData(this);
    };
    retrieveReq.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I replied in the other forum but I post here as reference and with more technical details.
The `to` attribute of `phonecall` entity is a `partylist` type, this means that it can handle several records from different entities. In your case you want to get the Parent Account (field `parentcustomerid`) if a contact is inside the `to` field.

Your first code contains same typo and use the msdn Retrieve example, the second code uses CRM 4.0 endpoints, they are still supported inside CRM 2011, but it's better to avoid them so you can use the REST endpoint instead of the SOAP one.

a working code in your case can be:

```js
function setToParentAccount() {
    // set only if to Field (Recipient) has 1 record and is a contact
    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue() != null) {
        var recipient = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to").getValue();
        if (recipient.length == 1 && recipient[0].entityType == "contact") {

            var contactId = recipient[0].id;
            var serverUrl;
            if (Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl !== undefined) {
                serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
            } else {
                serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
            }

            var ODataPath = serverUrl + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc"; 
            var contactRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            contactRequest.open("GET", ODataPath + "/ContactSet(guid'" + contactId + "')", false); 
            contactRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
            contactRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

            contactRequest.send();
            if (contactRequest.status === 200) {
                var retrievedContact = JSON.parse(contactRequest.responseText).d;
                var parentAccount = retrievedContact.ParentCustomerId;

                if (parentAccount.Id != null && parentAccount.LogicalName == "account") {
                    var newParentAccount = new Array();
                    newParentAccount[0] = new Object();
                    newParentAccount[0].id = parentAccount.Id;
                    newParentAccount[0].name = parentAccount.Name;
                    newParentAccount[0].entityType = parentAccount.LogicalName;
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("str_companyid").setValue(newParentAccount);
                } else {
                    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("str_companyid").setValue(null);
                }
            } else {
                    alert("error");
            }
        } else {
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("str_companyid").setValue(null);
        }
    }
}
```

to be called inside OnLoad event and OnChange event of the `to` field.